# How to generate confusion matrix with a custom generator

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, generator

I have implemented  my own custom data generator and I am using `model.predict_generator(generator = testing_generator, steps=steps,verbose=0)` to generate my predictions. In order to generate confusion maps I am using:

```
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(testing_generator.classes, y_predict,labels=classes)
```

I am getting an error

> 'generator' object has no attribute 'classes'

This is obviously because I did not implement any method to return all the GT back from the generator. I am not sure how to implement such a thing?

my generator has the general form:

```
    def generator_interference(self,number_of_steps_per_batch):   

        for i in range(number_of_steps_per_batch):
            """
            Some code to generates batches of samples
            :return: 
            """
            yield features, labels
```

How can I retrieve the GT to create a confusion matrix? can I simply add a variable named `self.classes` and accumulate the labels? If so, how do I clear it between predictions?